# How to escape " in windows power shell

Tags: powershell, escaping, double-quotes

It seems that back-slash doesn't work:

```
> echo "[{\"name\": \"oren\"}]" > input.json
> type .\input.json
[{\
name\: \oren\}]
```

Comment: This topic is already largely covered. Although it's nice to have the will to share infos, this is a duplicate

Comment: @Cid I agree - I somehow missed that

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShellEscape.htm#:%7E:text=The%20PowerShell%20escape%20character%20is,coded%20Distinguished%20Name%20in%20PowerShell.):

> The PowerShell escape character is the backtick "`" character

And indeed:

```
> echo "[{`"name`": `"oren`"}]" > input.json
> type .\input.json
[{"name": "oren"}]
```

Strangely enough, this info is not (easily?) found in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/?view=powershell-7.2)